# awk without printing a newline for multiple files

Tags: awk, scripting, newline

I have a (hopefully) quick and easy question which is driving me a bit bonkers! I have a bunch of files, and I want to print $1 from them. The files each have a few lines of output, let's say two. So if I print $1 from one file I might get something like this:

1 0

However, what I'm trying to do is print from all the files as such:

```
awk '{printf $1}' files*
```

When I do that, the output is basically just one long line: 1110000111100000...etc. NOT what I want. I want the output to be like this:

```
1 0 
0 1
1 1
```

So that each line represents the output from each file.

I tried:

```
awk 'BEGIN { ORS=" " }; { print $1}'
```

and quite a few iterations, so far no success. I know this should be simple, yet the answer has alluded me and help would be appreciated. For the record, this is NOT for any class, just my own work. Also, I did look on other posts here and elsewhere, and nothing has worked thus far. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{printf "%s%s", (FNR>1 ? OFS : ors), $0; ors=ORS} END{print ""}' file*
```

Explaination: For every line it prints something (controlled by the ternary expression) followed by the contents of the line. That something is a newline for the first line of every file except the first file (controlled by not setting ors until after the first line is read), and a blank char for every other line. Once done with all files it prints a terminating newline.

Comment: Thank you Ed, that appears to work! Just to double check, for any column I want, I'll just change $0 to that column, correct? Also, could you please explain how the script works? Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

In GNU awk (gawk) try the following:

```
awk '{printf "%s ", $1} ENDFILE {print ""}' files*
```

The first printf does prints $1 separated by a space.

The second print prints a newline after each file.

Comment: That will print an extra blank character at the end of every output line.